# How to access a URL on port 80 via android browser

Tags: android, port

my android device cannot access a URL:

```
http://myip:8080/alias
```

I tried another port of my service (80, running a service apache too) and works!
The tests, i'm doing from web browser of my device.
From my computer (on same network), both URL works!

The problem like a firewall. I cant access a port different of 80.

Thanks,

Comment: Be sure that you can access the website from a [i]different[/i] computer on the network. It sounds to me like you might running the website on one computer and checking to see if it works from that same computer. You need to try it from a different computer on that same network before you come to any conclusions. Android should be working just as well as any other computer. Also make sure the Android device is actually connected to the WiFi network.

Comment: More information: the URL is on internet (valid IP, etc)

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the problem is related to your web service rather than your android device, as you should be able to access pages on non-80 ports without any issue.

Have you tried using fiddler or another debugging proxy to check the response from the server?

If not, this may be useful

http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid

Edit: also, you mention that you can view it on port 80 on your android device, perhaps try disabling your firewall on your PC?

Comment: Billy, the firewall was disabled. From another devices android and computer, the URL works.